# How to change an element's visibility based on .change of a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to show `#comparelist` if any of `.addtocomparelist` checkboxes is checked, and hide it if it is unchecked. `#compare` list has `display: none;` in css.

```
    $('.addtocomparelist').change(function(e) {
         $('#comparelist').toggle();
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
              var x = $(this).val();
              var img = $('#' + x).find('.productimage img').attr('src');
              var name = $('#' + x).find('.productname').text();
              $('#comparelist').find('ul').append('<li id="c'+x+'"><a href="#"><img src="'+img+'">'+name+'</a><a href="#" class="deleteitem"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></li>');
         } else {
              var x = $(this).val();
              $('#c' + x).remove();
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to show #comparelist if any of .addtocomparelist checkboxes is checked*

You need to use [.toggle( showOrHide )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

> A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

Use

```
$('#comparelist').toggle($('.addtocomparelist').is(':checked'));
```

### EDIT

*how can I add 'fast' to toggle, where should I put it* In this you need to use `.show()` and `.hide()`

Example

```
var isChecked = $('.addtocomparelist').is(':checked')
if(isChecked){
    $('#comparelist').show('fast'); //You can use slideDown
}else{
    $('#comparelist').hide('fast'); //You can use slideUp
}
```